# Vue: On route change, render page only when finished loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

Whenever I go to a route that I haven't previously gone to in the current session, the page loads and the styles are only applied ~2 seconds after the page is rendered. This results in CSS flashing (ie FOUC), and it's not good at all in terms of user experience.

To fix this, the best way I can think of is to only render the page when it's finished loading.

How can I do this?

In addition, there are some other CSS issues, perhaps related to the above:

Here's a live example of the issue: http://archy-user.name/

When you click on "Name Search" or "Weight Table", the page contents are rendered first, and then the CSS is applied. This doesn't happen with the other two pages. I haven't attached any CSS frameworks to the other two, only to "Name Search" and "Weight Table".

Seems like that is the issue, but how can I fix this?

Another problem is that, if when in "Name Search" or "Weight Table" pages you refresh the page, the CSS framework is not loaded at all, although the normal CSS is.

The root of both issues seems to be the CSS frameworks, considering the pages without them work fine.

Does anyone know how to fix or workaround this?

Here's how my components are structured, "Weight Table" in the example:

```
<template>
<div class="weightconverter-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-3"> Weight Converter </h1>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="filter" placeholder="Input weight..." @input="calculate">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="results">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Weightconverter',
    methods: {
        calculate
    },
    head: {
        link: [
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                type: 'text/css',
                href: 'css/bootstrap.min.css'
            }
        ]
    },
    created() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$nuxt.$loading.start()

        setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 200)
        })
    }
}

function calculate(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let results = document.getElementById('results');

    let kilograms = Math.round(value / 2.205);
    let grams = Math.round(value * 453.592);
    let ounces = Math.round(value * 16);
    results.innerHTML = `
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
    Grams:
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    <str>`+grams+`</str></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
    Kilograms: </div>
     <div class="card-body">
<str>`+kilograms+`</str></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
    Ounces:
    </div>
     <div class="card-body">
<str>`+ounces+`</str></div>
    </div>
    `
}
</script>

<style scoped>

.weightconverter-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

h1 {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

</style>
```

PS - The reloading doesn't work only in the remote server, on localhost reloading works fine. (Although there's still FOUC)

PS2 - The project was built with "npm run generate"

Comment: What if you load the css in nuxt.config.js?

Comment: If I loaded it there, the frameworks would be loaded in every page, and it's not necessary, so that would be the last resort... I'm new to Vue so I'm not sure about this, but the CSS for the current page is only loaded when it's requested, right? Or is it loaded whenever you request the homepage, regardless of the file being used in the homepage? I.e. - If in the root index.html I don't link the specific file, but link it in another page, would the file be downloaded by the client regardless?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a conditional rendering to render when your data is loaded. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: Is there a method for page loading? Such as "this.loaded"?

Comment: @Slins there is a beforeMount() and mounted() event, here is a lifecycle article [link](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle)  hope it helps :)